# Bulma Navbar-Item color when clicked

Tags: css, bulma

What is the class name to change the color of a navbar-item in Bulma when it is clicked or chosen?  There is nothing in the documentation that says there is a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `:active` state, you could overwrite one or both of the active state SCSS variables for the navbar item:

```
$navbar-item-active-color
$navbar-item-active-background-color
```